# Borel and Abel resummation and zeta regularization

Tags: divergent-series

is ist posible to apply Borel resummation to sums of the form

$$ 1-2^{s}+3^{s}-4^{s}+....=\eta(-s) $$

of course the idea is to link zeta regularization and Borel summation since

$$ \eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta (s) $$

using Borel summastion plus the Theta operator $ \Theta = (x\partial_{x}) $

i think that borel resummation should be equaivalent to Abel resummation and equal to

$$ \eta (-s)= (\Theta )^{s}\frac{x}{1+x}$$